# Product involving function of two dependent Gaussian random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose that I have two independent random variables $g_1,g_2\sim N(0,1)$.

From these variables I construct a vector: $g=(g_1,g_2)$.

Also, I have a unit vector $u=(u_1,u_2)$.

It follows that the inner product $\langle u,g\rangle=u_1g_1+u_2g_2$ follows a normal distribution with the parameters $0$ and $u_1^2+u_2^2=1$, i.e., $\langle u,g\rangle\sim N(0,1)$.

How do I find the expected value $E(g_1 \operatorname{sign}{\langle u,g\rangle})$?

One approach is to claim that gaussian variable is rotation invariant, so we can take $u=(1,0)$ and in this case $E(g_1 \operatorname{sign}{\langle u,g\rangle})=E(g_1 \operatorname{sign}(g_1)$ which can be easily calculated.

But what is the justification of such approach? Is there some "direct" way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u_1 \neq 0$. Then $h\equiv u_1^{-1}g_1- \langle u, g \rangle$ is independent of $\langle u, g \rangle$ because these variables are jointly normal and their covariance is, by a routine calcualtion,  $0$. Note that $g_1=u_1h+u_1\langle u, g \rangle$.

Hence, $E(g_1 sign \langle u, g \rangle)=E(u_1h sign \langle u, g \rangle)+E(u_1\langle u, g \rangle sign \langle u, g \rangle)$. By independence, $E(u_1h sign \langle u, g \rangle)=u_1 Eh E( sign \langle u, g \rangle)=0$. Also, $E(u_1\langle u, g \rangle sign \langle u, g \rangle)=u_1E|\langle u, g \rangle)|$ and this quantity is just $E|X|$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$. SO the answer is $u_1E|X|=u_1\sqrt {\frac 2 {\pi}}$.

The case $u_1=0$ is trivial.

Comment: $h=u_1^{-1}g_1-\langle u,g\rangle$. How is $h$ independent of $\langle u,g\rangle$ if its value depends on $\langle u,g\rangle$?

Comment: A special property of jointly normal random variables is they are independent if their covariance is $0$. This is a technical result and you cannot get this just  from intuition. Two random variables may ''appear" to be dependent on each other but they may be independent. @eMathHelp

Comment: It is just not obvious that their covariance is zero.

Comment: @eMathHelp You have to do some routine calculations on your own. $E(h\langle u, g \rangle)=E(u_1^{-1}g_1-\langle u, g \rangle)\langle u, g \rangle)$ can you calculate this knowing that $\langle u, g \rangle=u_1g_1+u_1g_2$?

Comment: I can do that. Thank you!

Comment: I just wonder how did you notice that they are independent.

Comment: It is general fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, then there exists a constant $c$ such that $X+cY$ and $Y$ are independent. This is very useful and my argument is based on this. @eMathHelp

Answer (score 1):

We have  $g_3=u_1g_1+u_2g_2\sim N(0,1).$ Then cov$(g_1,g_3)=u_1$ and $g_1=u_1g_3+ u_2 Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ is independent of $g_3.$ Finally
$$E(g_1\mathrm{sign}(g_3))=u_1E(g_3\mathrm{sign}(g_3))+u_2E(Z\mathrm{sign}(g_3))=u_1E(|g_3|)+0=u_1\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}.$$

Comment: How did you get $g_1=u_1g_3+u_2Z$?

Comment: Answer: $(g_1,g_3)$ is Gaussian with margins $N(0,1)$ and correlation $\rho =u_1.$ as a consequence the correlation between $g_1-\rho g_3$ and $g_3$ is zero. Zero correlation here means independence.

Comment: That is clear. I don't understand the $u_2Z$ term.

Comment: OK. You agree that $G_4=g_1-u_1g_3$ is $N(0, \sigma^2)?$ We compute $\sigma^2=1+u_1^2-2u_1^2=u_2^2.$  Therefore $G_4=\pm Z$ according to the sign of $u_2.$

Comment: Thank you. It is clear now.